Raspberry Pi 2 Model B not working after years of storage
When booting my old Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, it freezes with a rainbow screen. At the same time, the ACT LED flickers 2 times, then blinks 1 time, then turns off.
I already tried different chargers, including exactly the one that I used years ago when it worked. I'm also using the exact SD card that I used back then. fsck finds no issues with the file system. I used Raspberry Pi Imager v1.8.5 to write Ubuntu 22.04 image onto the SD card. Unfortunately, I currently only have this SD card.
I haven't used this Raspberry Pi for many years now, it was stored in a small paper box in a drawer.
What is the most likely culprit here? Is there a likelihood that the board itself is broken?

Ubuntu probably won't run on an old Pi with limited memory.
Install Raspberry Pi OS Legacy which is the recommended OS .

Thank you. I just tried Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Release 5.2 March 2024 and it appears to boot now (although it didn't finished to boot yet).
